# ROS Qt media not showing until re make

Tags: qt, ubuntu, cmake, phonon, ros

I have a Smach state machine that communicates with a Qt app via ROS middleware to display a dynamic GUI based on what the Smach state passes to the GUI. Video and Audio is used with the help of Phonon libraries, however, each time I start up Ubuntu virtual machine that has this setup on it, Video, Sound and images cannot be displayed until I `make` the project again. I have tried on a dedicated Ubuntu machine as I thought VirtualBox may be causing some issues, but the issue remains. When I `make` the project again the video, sound and images instantly show up on the GUI.

I am using the Qt libraries along with ROS electric but it is created into one project and compiled using CMake.

Does anyone have any idea why the project would need to be made each time the machine is turned on? Is there a possibility that certain libs are not being linked properly until the project is re made?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Jacob

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.

In the XML sent from the smach , I was using a relative path for all the images and videos which for some reason was only correct when the app had been made. Once the system restarted the path was no longer correct so for now an absolute path is working.